# How to open .ics file in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Data representation of a .ics file. I want to open it, so it can create an Event in Calendar. How can I achieve that functionality using Swift?

Comment: .ics is plain text. Most likely there are third party ICS Parser.

Comment: The ICS spec is well documented, so you could also write your own parser.